# Error: Incompatible lockfileVersion in gitlab

Tags: angular, npm, dockerfile

I am in need of Assist here with my Gitlab build failure.

I am using https://github.com/beevelop/docker-ionic Docker image and i believe that it doesn't have latest version updated for npm and ionic and that is reason i am facing following problem.

please do suggest if any other Cause possible for this Error.

can i change npm version to latest from my Dokerfile ?

```
$ npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-13T07_24_58_534Z-debug.log
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM beevelop/ionic
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -qq -y
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli  \
    && npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Match your local npm with the one you have in the CI pipeline. Warn explains expliclity that newer NPM was used to create lock file then the one that is used on the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you Antoniossss, i have solved it by deleting old packagelock and generated new one.it worked.